# How can I make a diagram like this in LaTeX?

Tags: tables

How can I make a chart like this in LaTeX?

[image: Chart with lines between boxes]

Comment: Please include title or class of diagram's in the Q Title instead of `this` for easy traceability/searchable for future users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is using `tikz` package. Minimal introduction can be found [here](http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf). Another solution is MetaPost which may be though as prototype of `tikz`, they have much in common. But MetaPost is not package for TeX-file, it's external tool for creation of eps-images with back connection to TeX of LaTeX. It is included particularly in MiKTeX. Read manual [here](http://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution using Tikz matrix node

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,%
        boxes/.style={draw, rectangle,%
                thick,minimum height=6mm,%
                text width=6mm, 
                align=center}]

    \matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, nodes=boxes,
             row sep=1cm,column sep=1cm]
    {
   |(A-3-1)|  & |(A-3-2)|   & |(A-3-3)|   & |(A-3-4)|  & |(A-3-5)| \\                              
   |(A-2-1)|  & |(A-2-2)|   & |(A-2-3)|   & |(A-2-4)|  & |(A-2-5)| \\                              
   |(A-1-1)|  & |(A-1-2)|   & |(A-1-3)|   & |(A-1-4)|  & |(A-1-5)| \\                                             
    };
    \foreach \i/\j in {3/2,2/1}
   {
        \draw  (A-\i-1)--(A-\j-1);        \draw  (A-\i-2)--(A-\j-2);
        \draw  (A-\i-3)--(A-\j-3);        \draw  (A-\i-5)--(A-\j-5);
    }
    \draw  (A-1-3)--(A-1-4)--(A-1-5);
    \draw  (A-3-3)--(A-3-4)--(A-3-5);
    \draw  (A-3-1.south east) -- (A-2-2.north west)      
       (A-2-2.south east) -- (A-1-3.north west);
    \draw  (A-3-2.south east) -- (A-2-3.north west)      
       (A-2-3.south east) -- (A-1-4.north west);
    \draw  (A-3-3.south east) -- (A-2-4.north west)      
       (A-2-4.south east) -- (A-1-5.north west);
    \node [red] at (A-3-5) {9}; 
    \node [red] at (A-1-3) {4}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

An example of similar diagram (with TikZ)

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/kalman-filter/

Comment: Thanks, though I already figured it out.

Comment: This is an interesting link.  However, a link only "Answer" is usually better as a comment.  Alternatively, you can expand your "Answer" to explain how to work with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, I did it with a stack...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}[2013-10-15]
\usepackage{graphicx, xcolor}
\def\thk{.2pt}
\def\sz{1.3ex}
\def\sqt{1.40}
\def\hgap{.72ex}
\def\hrl{\rule{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox-\thk}{\thk}}
\def\vrl{\rule{\thk}{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox-\thk}}
\newcommand\drl{\rotatebox{135}{\rule{\sqt\ht\strutbox+\sqt\dp\strutbox}{\thk}}}
\def\nhrl{\rule{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}{0pt}}
\def\nvrl{\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}}
\def\nnrl{\rule{\thk}{\thk}}
\newcommand\ndrl{\rotatebox{45}{\rule{\sqt\ht\strutbox+\sqt\dp\strutbox}{0pt}}}
\newcommand\fsq[1]{\fboxsep=0pt\fboxrule=0.2pt\hspace{\hgap}%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\tiny #1}{%
  \fbox{\colorbox{white}{\rule{\sz}{0ex}\rule{0ex}{\sz}}}}\hspace{\hgap}}
\begin{document}
\setstackgap{S}{-.15pt}
\def\stacktype{L}
\stackon[-2.7pt]{%
\Shortstack[l]{
\nnrl\nhrl\nnrl\nhrl\nnrl\hrl \nnrl\hrl\nnrl\\
\vrl \drl \vrl \drl \vrl \drl \nvrl\nhrl\vrl\\
\nnrl\nhrl\nnrl\nhrl\nnrl\nhrl\nnrl\nhrl\nnrl\\
\vrl \nhrl\vrl \drl \vrl \drl \nvrl\drl\vrl\\
\nnrl\nhrl\nnrl\nhrl\nnrl\hrl \nnrl\hrl\nnrl}
}{\kern-3.3pt\Longstack{%
\fsq{}\fsq{}\fsq{}\fsq{}\fsq{9}\\
\fsq{}\fsq{}\fsq{}\fsq{}\fsq{}\\
\fsq{}\fsq{}\fsq{4}\fsq{}\fsq{}}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]